# how to do web scraping for multiple choice questions with answers and fetch data in proper way in excel sheet?

Tags: extension-methods

I am doing web scraping,but while scraping data from website to an excel sheet,it is not showing the data in a sequential order. I have tried with lot of looping concepts like parent and child cases but even still no proper solution for the extration of data

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what is the exact problem you are facing?.
We can't suggest methodologies but we can help in the problems you face while implementing a methodology

Comment: i want to scrap the multiple choice question with answer from a website to an excel sheet bt after scrapping it is showing the gap and the question and answer are not comming in proper sequence.